# Capture Bash output to variable in Shell Script

Tags: bash, sh

I have written a shell script to run other shell script on **remote server**(Shell script is running successfully on remote server). I want to capture output to some variable. Below is my code.

Please can anyone help me out.

```
#! /bin/sh
sshpass -p password ssh -T root@serverIP1 << EOF
sshpass -p password ssh -T root@serverIP2 << EOS
copyoutput=bash /opt/Shellscriptlocation/DiskSpace.sh
EOS
EOF
echo $copyoutput
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you by placing command substitution in outermost shell:

```
copyoutput=$(
sshpass -p password ssh -T root@serverIP1 << EOF
sshpass -p password ssh -T root@serverIP2 << EOS
bash /opt/Shellscriptlocation/DiskSpace.sh
EOS
EOF
)

echo "$copyoutput"
```

Comment: capturing output but also printing 

**logintoserver.sh: line 13: warning: here-document at line 9 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')**